# Teamcity MSBuild error:MSB3030

Tags: c#, msbuild, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

My project is building successfully on my local. But in teamcity I am getting the below error:

```
ResolveProjectReferences] MSBuild
[08:08:37][MSBuild] xxx.csproj: Build default targets
[08:08:38][xxx.csproj] _CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory
[08:08:38][_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory] Copy
[08:08:38][Copy] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3683, 5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "D:\BuildAgent\work\9e680eb13f39fb7c\src\xxx\Helpers\PowerYaml\Libs\YamlDotNet.Converters.dll" because it was not found.
[08:08:38][xxx.csproj] Project xxx.csproj failed.
```

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong and how to resolve it?

Added part of csproj for PowerYaml stuff:

```
<Content Include="Helpers\PowerYaml\Libs\YamlDotNet.Configuration.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Helpers\PowerYaml\Libs\YamlDotNet.Converters.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Helpers\PowerYaml\Libs\YamlDotNet.Core.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Helpers\PowerYaml\Libs\YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
```

Comment: This doesn't look like TeamCity problem. Are you sure your YamlDotNet.Converters.dll library is present in your version control repository? You might have it just locally. Could you show us your *.csproj file?

Comment: @Przemek , I have added sinppet of csproj file where PowerYaml files are referred. Also the files are checkedin to TFS.